# What is the area of x given some areas in this parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

[image: diagram]

So I understand and got to the point that triangle ADE + triangle EGB = 1/2[ABCD] and same goes for triangle EDG + triangle BGC = 1/2[ABCD]. I'm now stuck on how to start and figure out the pieces, if someone could guide me through this that would be very nice. I don't know what do do with the areas given.

Comment: Note that the yellow area has to equal the area of triangle $ADF$ and hence $$x+48+3=57+7$$

Comment: Right that was like the easiest thing, how didn't I think of that haha. Thank you.